# Does the dangling modifier thing apply?

Tags: modifiers

I have a persistent question concerning grammar that I would really like your help on. It has been nagging me for a long time.

So, as we all know, if you start a sentence with -ing, the first word of the following phrase/clause has to be the subject that the -ing is modifying.

A: Feeling dejected, Tom left the pub.
Tom--the one feeling dejected.

B: Swimming across the ocean, the old man pushes forward with every ounce of strength he has got.
The old man--the one swimming across ocean.

However, when -ing occurs in mid sentence and at the start of a clause/phrase, does the "dangling modifier" rule still apply?

C. Pancreatic cancer is common among the elderly, necessitating the need for screening in the specific population.

Here, pancreatic cancer itself does not necessitate screening - it is the whole situation (P cancer common among the elderly) that necessitates the screening. But I read sentences like that all the time.

D. The company will experience slow growth, driving the need to seek for new income sources.

Here, the company itself does not drive the need -again, it is the situation ( slow growth ) that is "driving the need".

So, I would like to know if :

1. C/D are correct or they are plain wrong.
2. the -ing occurs at the start of the phrase/clause but not the start of a sentence (i.e. C/D) - does the "dangling modifier" rule still apply?

Or starting with -ing in the second clause/phrase is a whole other thing (which means it serves more of a transitioning function and not intending to modify anything?)

Comment: C and D are fine.  The -ing verbs in each refer to the entire preceding clause. (Note: you can drop the *for* after *seek*.)

Comment: The _ing_ clauses ae **not** modifiers but supplementary adjuncts.

Comment: Thank you so much , everyone !

Comment: The rule "we all know" is, as usual, the wrong rule. That's what we get here on ELU.